# Error: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using '''youtube_player_iframe: ^2.1.0''' package for displaying YouTube video in Flutter web app. The video is playing absolutely fine but it gives this error whenever i tap on full screen to play video in full screen also it do not make the video to come on full screen and return to its previous size

ERROR

```
Error: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:5041:11)
    at _AsyncBroadcastStreamController.new.add (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:31586:44)
    at controller.YoutubePlayerController.new.add (http://localhost:42339/packages/youtube_player_iframe/src/helpers/youtube_value_builder.dart.lib.js:894:32)
    at http://localhost:42339/packages/youtube_player_iframe/src/helpers/youtube_value_builder.dart.lib.js:469:29
    at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:5246:16)
    at Object.dcall (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:5251:17)
    at http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:100646:100
Error: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:5041:11)
    at _AsyncBroadcastStreamController.new.add (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:31586:44)
    at controller.YoutubePlayerController.new.add (http://localhost:42339/packages/youtube_player_iframe/src/helpers/youtube_value_builder.dart.lib.js:894:32)
    at http://localhost:42339/packages/youtube_player_iframe/src/helpers/youtube_value_builder.dart.lib.js:469:29
    at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:5246:16)
    at Object.dcall (http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:5251:17)
    at http://localhost:42339/dart_sdk.js:100646:100
```

CODE :

```
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';
    
    class YoutubePlayerWeb extends StatefulWidget {
      final String url;
    
      const YoutubePlayerWeb({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);
      
    
      @override
      _YoutubePlayerState createState() => _YoutubePlayerState();
    }
    
    class _YoutubePlayerState extends State<YoutubePlayerWeb> {
      late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
    
      void runYoutubePlay()
      {
        _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
          initialVideoId: YoutubePlayerController.convertUrlToId(widget.url).toString(),
          params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
            showControls: true,
            desktopMode: true,
            showFullscreenButton: true,
            privacyEnhanced: true,
            showVideoAnnotations: true ,
            autoPlay: false,
            enableCaption: true,
            color: 'red',
          )
        );
      }
    
      void youtubePlayerFullScreen()
      {
        _controller.onEnterFullscreen = ()
        {
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
            DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
            DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
          ]);
          print("ENTERED FULLSCREEN");
        };
        _controller.onExitFullscreen = ()
        {
          print("EXITED FULLSCREEN");
        };
      }
      
      @override
      void initState() {
          runYoutubePlay();
          youtubePlayerFullScreen();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _controller.close();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        const player = YoutubePlayerIFrame();
        return YoutubePlayerControllerProvider(controller: _controller, child: player);
      }
    
    }
```

Please Help me and please tell where am i going wrong ?

Comment: If you open an issue in the github account of the package, you can get clearer help there.

Comment: If you are building a web application, and this occurs when you tap on the full screen, I believe it relates to event capturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that an event is being tried to be used on `YoutubePlayerController` after it has been closed on `dispose()`. A checker can be used to see if `_controller` is still open.

```dart
if (!_controller.isClosed){
  // Add events
}
```